# Using scrapy and scrapy-playwright behind proxy

Tags: proxy, scrapy, scrapy-playwright

I try to run two spiders behind company proxy. One spider is scrapy spider ("quotes") and one scrapy-playwright spider(quotes-playwright):

```
from typing import Iterable
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from macro_scrapy.items import QuoteItem
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
    ]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css("div.quote"):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first().replace("\u201c","").replace("\u201d",""),
                'author': quote.css("small.author::text").extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css("div.tags a.tag::text").extract(),
            }
        


class QuotesScrollSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotesscroll'

    def start_requests(self):
        url ="http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll"
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta=dict(
            playwright= True,
            playwright_include_page= True,
            playwright_page_methods= [
                PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div.quote"),
                PageMethod("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"),
                PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div.quote:nth-child(15)"),
            ],
            errBack=self.handle_failure
        ))

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        screeshot= await page.screenshot(path="screenshot.png", full_page=True)
        await page.close()

    async def handle_failure(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

I also have this settings in settings.py:

```
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}
PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {
        "headless": True,
        }
PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {
    "proxy": {
        "server": os.environ.get("SERVER"),
        "username": os.environ.get("USERNAME"),
        "password": os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
        },
    }
```

I have SERVER, USERNAME and PASSWORD in environment variables and scrapy-playwright uses them and`scrapy crawl quotesscroll` works. However I need to add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY as environment variables in order to run `scrapy crawl quotes`(I do not need to load them explicitly through os.environ.get()). But if I add them the scrapy-playwright (quotesscroll) stops working. I tried to run `scrapy crawl quotesscroll` in different terminal of vscode and as there was not HTTP_PROXY assigned, it worked again.

Is there a way to run both in one terminal?